# Informatica : Can not rename workflow log file

Tags: informatica, tivoli

I all

I have a job schudled by tivoli for an Informatica workflow.
i have checked property to save workflow logs for 5 runs.

Job is running fine through informatica but if u try to run is from tivoli using pmcmd it fails to rename the workflow log file .

pLease help , i am getting this error :

**Cannot rename workflow log file [E:\Informatica\etl_d\WorkflowLogs\wf_T.log.bin] to [E:\Informatica\etl_d\WorkflowLogs\wf_T.log.4.bin].  Please check the Integration Service log for more information.
Disconnecting from Integration Service**

Comment: Any chance to check the log from Informatica?

Answer (score 0):

Check the log file name in Workflow Edit options. Possibly you have same workflow log file name for multiple workflows.

HTH
Irfan